# Another Maybe for "find minimum" functions

Tags: haskell, option-type

Maybe is useful when we are searching "maximum" value and unconvinient for finding minimum

```
-- update maximum could be used as "lambda"
updateMaximum :: (Ord a) => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
updateMaximum saved new = max new saved
    
-- update minimum could't be used as "lambda"
updateMinimum Nothing new = new
updateMinimum saved Nothing = saved
updateMininum saved new = min new saved
```

The ideal solution would be the **standard** monad  with another constructors order, but i didn't find it:

```
data Maybe' a = Just' a | Notheing'
-- all standard functions implementations:
safeHaad' :: [a] -> Maybe' a
...
```

**So the issue is: what is the standart way in haskell for writing "updateMinimum" function?**

P.S.
Two possible solutions are available, but each with its own disadvantage:

- change problem wording: find minimum of function "f()" -> find maximum of funciton "0-f()"
- Use "MyMaybe" with swapped constructors order: data MyMaybe a = Value a | None

Comment: What is _used as "lambda"_ supposed to mean?

Comment: By the way, I think that the question could be improved a lot. A trivial example of what outputs is desired for some relevant inputs is the minimum (ahahah), in my opinion.

Comment: > What is used as "lambda" supposed to mean? 
anonimous function (as a map 1st argument for example)

> A trivial example of what outputs is desired for some relevant inputs
updateMinimum (Just 5) (Just 3) == Just 3
updateMinimum Notheing (Just 3) == Just 3
updateMunimum (Just 5) Notheing == Just 5

Comment: You should add those details in the question, so that it is clearer for the next reader too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monoid-extras package provides the [`Inf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.6.1/docs/Data-Monoid-Inf.html) data type, with variants `PosInf` and `NegInf`, for exactly this purpose. Your two functions look like this:

```
updateMaximum :: Ord a => NegInf a -> NegInf a -> NegInf a
updateMaximum = max

updateMinimum :: Ord a => PosInf a -> PosInf a -> PosInf a
updateMinimum = min
```

I wouldn't even bother naming them.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really want Nothing to be part of the ordering here, but instead to "be ignored" when you do a binary operation, or in other words to act like an identity.  This is the Monoid behaviour of Maybe, and we can use the Semigroup instances Min and Max.

```
updateMinimum x y = fmap getMin (fmap Min x <> fmap Min y)
updateMaximum x y = fmap getMax (fmap Max x <> fmap Max y)
```

The point-free version is not really an improvement but it looks like this:

```
updateMinimum = (fmap getMin .) . ((<>) `on` fmap Min)
```

Comment: I think this could also be written `updateMinimum = coerce ((<>) :: Maybe (Min a) -> _ -> _)` and similarly for the max. Besides being more efficient (the usual reason to use `coerce`). I think that would also more clearly convey the programmer intent (somewhat unusual for `coerce` in my experience).

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily wrap with `Down`, reversing the ordering, take the `max` under the reversed ordering, and then unwrap later:

```
import Data.Ord

updateMaximum :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
updateMaximum x y = max x y

updateMinimum :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
updateMinimum x y = getDown <$> max (Down <$> x) (Down <$> y)
```

Note the subtle part: we wrap under the `Maybe`, so that `Nothing` is still the least value even if we reversed the ordering. This makes `max` do the right thing.

A few tests confirm this works as needed. Below, the first two values are the test inputs, the third is the output.

```
max: (Nothing,Nothing,Nothing)
min: (Nothing,Nothing,Nothing)
max: (Nothing,Just 1,Just 1)
min: (Nothing,Just 1,Just 1)
max: (Nothing,Just 2,Just 2)
min: (Nothing,Just 2,Just 2)
max: (Just 1,Nothing,Just 1)
min: (Just 1,Nothing,Just 1)
max: (Just 1,Just 1,Just 1)
min: (Just 1,Just 1,Just 1)
max: (Just 1,Just 2,Just 2)
min: (Just 1,Just 2,Just 1)
max: (Just 2,Nothing,Just 2)
min: (Just 2,Nothing,Just 2)
max: (Just 2,Just 1,Just 2)
min: (Just 2,Just 1,Just 1)
max: (Just 2,Just 2,Just 2)
min: (Just 2,Just 2,Just 2)
```

Full code:

```
module Main where

import Data.Foldable
import Data.Ord

updateMaximum :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
updateMaximum x y = max x y

updateMinimum :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
updateMinimum x y = getDown <$> max (Down <$> x) (Down <$> y)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let xs = [ Nothing, Just 1, Just 2 ] :: [Maybe Int]
    for_ xs $ \x ->
      for_ xs $ \y -> do
        putStr "max: "
        print (x, y, updateMaximum x y)
        putStr "min: "
        print (x, y, updateMinimum x y)
    pure ()
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on [David Fletcher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70914963/5825294) there's even a terser solution, which is still point free, but I feel a bit clearer because it hides the convoluted double use of `.` into an ad-hoc operator `.:` from the module `Data.Composition`:

```hs
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Composition ((.:))
-- (.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d

updateMinimum :: (Ord a) => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
updateMinimum = fmap getMin .: ((<>) `on` fmap Min)
```

where the definition of `updateMinimum` encodes this flow of data

```
                               ┌───────────┐
                              ┌┤fmap getMin├─ first input
        ┌───────────┐  ┌────┐ │└───────────┘
output ─┤fmap getMin├──┤(<>)├─┤
        └───────────┘  └────┘ │┌───────────┐
                              └┤fmap getMin├─ second input
                               └───────────┘
```